# Query in a DataFrame with column names with spaces

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have this df: `d = DataFrame(Symbol("Full Name") => ["Mike","Paul","Andres"], Symbol("Age") => 10:12)`
so far so good.
Now i want to do this Query:

```
using Query
@from i in d begin
@where i.Age == 11
@select {i."Full Name", i.Age}
@collect DataFrame
end
```

But it returns an error. I think its because that "Full Name" field because it goes fine if the field name is just "Name".  How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be an issue, try using DataFrames directly:

```
d[ d.Age .== 11,  ["Full Name", "Age"] ]
```